# Reading of .tfrecord file

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, tfrecord

I am trying to read the tfrecord file but the code is showing errors. First I converted csv files into tfrecord file. I have given both the codes below, and the last block shows the error that I'm getting while reading the tfrecord file.

****************read .tfrecord file*****************************

```
data_path1 = 'C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/images/csv1.tfrecords'  # address to save the hdf5 file

with tf.Session() as sess:
    feature = {'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'image/object/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}
    # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path1], num_epochs=1)
    # Define a reader and read the next record
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    # Decode the record read by the reader
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
    # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
        image = tf.decode_raw(features['image/encoded'], tf.int64)

    # Cast label data into int32
    label = tf.cast(features['image/object/class/label'], tf.int32)
    # Reshape image data into the original shape
    image = tf.reshape(image, [150, 150, 1])
    images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)



with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize all global and local variables
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    #     sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init_op)
        # Create a coordinator and run all QueueRunner objects
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for batch_index in range(5):
            img, lbl = sess.run([images, labels])
            img = img.astype(np.uint8)
            for j in range(6):
                plt.subplot(2, 3, j+1)
                plt.imshow(img[j, ...])
                plt.show()
        # Stop the threads
    coord.request_stop()

        # Wait for threads to stop
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

---

****************csv to tfrecord file*******************************

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'car':
        return 1                                   
    else:
        return 0


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)+'.jpg'), 'rb') as fid:
        print(fid)
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():  
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('csv1.tfrecords')
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'thermal')
    examples = pd.read_csv('thermal_labels.csv')
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'csv1.tfrecords')
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

---

the error i am getting is
****************error*********************

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, Input to DecodeRaw has length 224949 that is not a multiple of 8, the size of int64
     [[Node: DecodeRaw = DecodeRaw[little_endian=true, out_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample)]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_37_shuffle_batch_2/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch_2 = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch_2/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch_2/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b8d05859b312> in <module>()
      8     threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
      9     for batch_index in range(5):
---> 10             img, lbl = sess.run([images, labels])
     11             img = img.astype(np.uint8)
     12             for j in range(6):

c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_37_shuffle_batch_2/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch_2 = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch_2/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch_2/n)]]

Caused by op 'shuffle_batch_2', defined at:
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 127, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 422, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1432, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 117, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2903, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-bd671b499233>", line 23, in <module>
    images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=10, capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 1300, in shuffle_batch
    name=name)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 846, in _shuffle_batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 483, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 3799, in queue_dequeue_many_v2
    component_types=component_types, timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\tf18\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_37_shuffle_batch_2/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch_2 = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch_2/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch_2/n)]]
```